# What is wrong with my express.js route configuration?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I have a server that is using Express to route requests.

In this I have the following route set up:

```
  productRouter = ProductRouter app 
  app.use '/', productRouter 
  app.use '/products/(videocloud|perform)/*', productRouter
  app.use '/user', UserRouter accountService: app.get('accountService'), setiClient: app.get('setiClient') # user endpoint for StudioModule client side SDK
```

The problem is that the route that is established to handle '/' requests is for some reason ahandling all requests that weren't rpreviously routed.  meaning that if a user attempts to navigate to '/user'  it get's handled by product router.

What is happening here, and what would the appropriate way to handle domain-level requests be?

Comment: What version of express are you using?

Comment: Does `productRouter` pass through routes it doesn't match? `app.use` just matches the prefix, so `'/'` will send every request through `productRouter` and then if it doesn't handler the request, it will propagate through to the rest of the routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.use '/', productRouter` runs the middleware productRouter at any request that has the prefix of `/` which would include all requests.

If you want to handle just the root domain request at /, use `app.get`, for example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

Comment: Good call, I didn't realize that the string match syntax for use was different from the syntax for app.VERB